# Rails loop through records in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 hstore columns (`parameters` and `keys`) defined in my PostgeSQL database. I want to get a list of keys and have defined a method for it in the model:

```
def self.keys_list
  logs = self
  list = Log.column_names - %w{id parameters extras}
  logs.each do |log|
    log.parameters.present? ? list << log.parameters.keys : list << []
    log.extras.present? ? list << log.extras.keys : list << []
  end
  list = list.flatten.uniq
  return list
end
```

But when I try using it, I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for #<Class:0x00000004b630b0>
```

Can anyone suggest where the error is or how to do it some other way?

Comment: logs = self; logs.each... self in this case would be the class that you are in so logs has been set to a class, perhaps you meant to set it to something else?

Comment: Let's say I have some logs. `logs = Log.where(name: "Peeyush")`. Now, I would like to get the list of keys for it. So, I want to make a call like `logs.keys_list` on it.

Comment: logs.map{|a| a.keys_list}.flatten I think would do it.. of course that expects Log to have defined a keys_list function for each individual log...

Comment: The `logs = self` bit is very confusing. Just use `self`.

Comment: I think you want what Matijs' answer suggests. Though, I would like to suggest one off topic.. You can write `log.parameters.present? ? list << log.parameters.keys : list << []` as `list << log.parameters.present? ? log.parameters.keys : []`. It removes the repetition and looks nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ActiveRecord::Base` does not define an `.each` method. You need to add in a call to `all`, like so:

```
all.each do |log|
  #...
end
```

This should make both `Log.keys_list` and `Log.where(name: "Peeyush").keys_list` work.